# reading a json file and selecting values with dojo

Tags: json, dojo

I'm trying to read a json file and select a value in the file, but my googling skills have failed me.

I've come across dojo.xhrGet & ItemFileReadStore, but I'm not sure which is the correct one to use.  Or are neither correct?

Any help or wave of a flashlight in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show your Json file contents and what value you want to extract from it, then we can precisely help you in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more specific. What do you mean by select a values in file? Using dojo you can perform all range of HTTP request(GET, POST, PUT etc) and specify if returened data is text or json.

```
    xhr.get({
      url:"data.json",
      handleAs:"json",
      load: function(data){
        for(var i in data){
           console.log("key", i, "value", data[i]);
        }
      }
   });
```

Here *data* can be treated as object and based on key data can be retrived using *obj.key* notation